# Editing SCSS using Chrome DevTools not working in Ionic project

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, google-chrome-devtools, ionic4

With web projects I always use the Chrome DevTools to modify the CSS of a page locally without reloading. It seems like this isn't working in my ionic4 project, serving the page simply with ionic serve. I can see the source file that I'd like to edit in the Sources -> Page section of the devtools, however when I make modifications here I don't see changes in the live page.

See the image below:

[image: example]

In the dev tools, I'd like to change #play-pause, lets say add a larger margin like margin-top: 20px. If I edit this in the Chrome DevTools I see no change. However, if I go to my IDE, make the same CSS change there and save, then the ionic dev server will restart automatically and the CSS change will be in effect.

If anyone has any clues or things to try, let me know, and thanks!

Comment: maybe it s an issue with your file watcher setting? Usually when you modify scss in your IDE, it will update the source css file, and the browser reads the css file, not scss. So if your file watcher is only set up in your IDE, what you're trying wont work

Comment: Ghybs, it works fine when I edit and save in the IDE, but does NOT work when using the Chrome DevTools.

Comment: take a look at this, and set it up with the same configs as your watcher was set up in your IDE. http://sassbreak.com/watch-your-sass/

Comment: This watches files in the filesystem for changes, I'm not modifying any files in my filesystem or in my IDE, I'm modifying them in the Chrome DevTools which is not touching the files on the filesystem, so the watcher will not work. When I build the page using my build process (actually it's ionic serve doing this) then everything works fine.

Comment: i ve never heard of that working, unless you have some plugins in chrome